# Cloud Functions: How do I obtain a specific json attribute's value?

Tags: node.js, json, attributes, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

My json file, which I input into the message box of the pubsub message I'm publishing, looks like this:

```
{
"message": "Good morning",
"sender": "Joe Schmoe"
}
```

I have attempted to access the value of "sender" in the following, unsuccessful ways:

```
console.log(decodedJson); //gives decoded json file

console.log("pubsubMessage.sender",pubsubMessage.sender); //returns undefined

console.log("decodedJson.sender",decodedJson.sender); //returns undefined

console.log("decodedJson['sender']",decodedJson["sender"]); //returns undefined

console.log("Decoded Json referencing using object.keys: The", 
Object.keys(decodedJson)[1], " is ", decodedJson[Object.keys(decodedJson)[1]]); //returns "The 1 is "

console.log("pubsubMessage referencing using object.keys: The", Object.keys(pubsubMessage)[1], " is ", pubsubMessage[Object.keys(pubsubMessage)[1]]); //returns "The 1 is w"

console.log("event.after.data().sender ",event.after.data().sender); //returns an error message
```

For reference, the two variables pubsubMessage and decodedJson are defined as follows:

```
const pubsubMessage = event.data;
const decodedJson=Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString();
```

Any help you can provide in showing my the way to access particular attribute values is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
exports.pubSubFn = (event, context) => {
  const pubsubMessage = event.data;
  parsed = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage, 'base64').toString());
  console.log("Sender:" + parsed.sender);
};
```

Comment: What if I'm adding attributes to message by clicking on "Add Attributes"? How can I read them?